# Weird concurrency issue with Flask (flask-restful) and MySQLdb (PyMySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-restful, pymysql

I have a flask-restful project that uses a MySQL database, I am currently using PyMysql to connect to the database, I previously tried to use flask-mysqldb and flask-mysql but they didn't really work out because I need to use the db connection *outside* the request method (for decorators primarily), so I started to use PyMySQL but now I found an issue with concurrency, whenever I try to make more than 2 concurrent requests at the same time (which means 2 concurrent queries) I get this error:

```
mysqldb._exceptions.programmingerror: (2014, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

I do in fact call `cursor.nextset` after each query to make sure the result is fully consumed, and I did make sure all my queries and stored procedures were correct and didn't have any problems, I was starting to think the issue was caused by the server using only one cursor as the cursor is defined in a separate module that all the views/resources import it to do work (they don't create a new cursor) but after I made every view/resource method create a new cursor to do work with and close it afterwards and I was still getting the same error.
this is how I execute queries:

```py
cursor.callproc('do_something', (arg1, arg2))
result = cursor.fetch_all()
cursor.nextset()
```

it doesn't have to do with race conditions either because the queries don't write anything. I tried to serve the application with Waitress but I still am getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And for **MySQLdb** Stored Procedure

```
cursor.callproc('do_something', (arg1, arg2))
```

Here you have to add for all out going parameters a variable

```
cursor.execute('SELECT @outparameter1, @outparameter2, @outparameter3')

cursor.fetchall()
```

for the **pymyslq** you need some more changes, as there is no callproc

```
cusrorType      = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor

 

databaseConnection   = pymysql.connect(host=hostName,

                                       user=userName,

                                       password=userPassword,

                                       db=databaseName,

                                       charset=databaseCharset,

                                       cursorclass=cusrorType)

                                    

try:

    # Cursor object creation

    cursorObject    = databaseConnection.cursor()                                    

 

    # Execute the sqlQuery

    cursorObject.execute("call do_something(?,?)",arg1, arg2)

 

    # Print the result of the executed stored procedure

    for result in cursorObject.fetchall():

        print(result)
```

For **mysq.connector**
You have to call `store_result before hand like

```
cursor.callproc('do_something', (arg1, arg2))
for result in cursor.stored_results():
    result.fetchall()
```

Comment: that doesn't work, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'stored_results'`

Comment: you are right this works only in mysql connerctor

Comment: @InfinityVive i added code for pymysql it has **no** callproc

Comment: ah, sorry, I am using MySQLdb, not PyMysql, I though they were the same thing, but based on what you're saying maybe they're different

Comment: that is even more complicated see example as i don't know your stored procedure